# Where does a TensorFlow model instance get `input` property from?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am **not** talking about how to pass an input to a model.

If you make a model, e.g. from the docs:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

`model` actually has a few properties (or attributes) which are not listed in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#attributes_1)... These include `input`, `inputs`, `name`, and much more. I've listed them with `dir()`, but surely its documented **somewhere**.

I would like to know what exactly these are. It really seems like a silly question. Maybe there is a different document I cannot find?

Comment: the model class is a subclass of `base_layer.Layer` and `version_utils.ModelVersionSelector`, so properties can come from those classes too.

Comment: Oh... so basically I needed to click the link that says "Inherits From: Layer", then there, click "Inherits From: Module", then I find the "name" attribute. Excellent, thanks jakub, you should write an answer... 

Comment: In summary, someone who knows python will confirm that was a silly question :D

Comment: It is not a silly question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [`tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) inherits from [`tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer), which inherits from [`tf.Module`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Module). The model instance will have attributes from those classes as well.

- `inputs` comes from `tf.keras.Model`. You pass `inputs=` when you create a model.
- `input` comes from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`
- `name` is defined in both `tf.keras.layers.Layer` and `tf.Module`